# Why might a perl CGI script fail to connect to MySQL, when it works from console?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, perl, cgi

I'm migrating to new server hardware, which also means learning the idiosyncrasies of a new Linux distribution (Debian buster).

I've got a Perl CGI script which when run from the console runs, but fails to connect to MySQL with:

> AH01215: DBI connect('my_db','my_db_user',...) failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Given it's running on the same hardware, so it'll be the same Perl install, etc. I'm at a loss as to why it's not working? I know back on Centos, SELinux could get in the way, but I don't believe Debian has this by default, but is there something similar that I'd need to do to allow child processes to make connections?

mysqladmin suggests that's the right place (i.e I'm not hitting [this issue](https://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=72626)):

```
# mysqladmin version -p
Enter password:
mysqladmin  Ver 8.0.17 for Linux on i686 (Source distribution)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version          8.0.17
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /tmp/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 3 days 26 min 34 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 74254  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 1042  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 962  Queries per second avg: 0.284
```

And the socket clearly exists (as executing from console works)

```
$ ls -lF /tmp/mysql.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Sep  6 22:33 /tmp/mysql.sock=
```

Comment: OK, so why the anonymous downvote? After all, I've at least tried to verify from the console, but that just works :/

Comment: Is the socket present? Do you have permissions to access it?

Comment: @Tomasz The socket is present and I have permissions to access it (after all, it works from the console)

Comment: But do you have access to it as www-data (or whoever the server runs as)?

Comment: @Tomasz the www-data user isn't granted log-on rights, so I can't switch to that user :/. The CGI script does partially run, just dies when trying to connect to MySQL via DBI, so I'm happy the permissions on that are sane. The MySQL sock file shows as world read & writable (and PHP scripts on the same apache install have no issue connecting, so I don't believe it'll be that) I'm curious if there's a setting disallowing CGI scripts to do onward connections (like selinux had) in a default Debian install?

Comment: root can always switch to any uid, even if have `/bin/false` or similar as a shell. e.g.  `su - www-data -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: BTW, does it work if you make DBI connect via TCP to the `127.0.0.1` rather than the `/tmp/mysql.sock` socket?   i.e. explicitly set the host in the connect args. 
 See `man DBD::Mysql`.

Comment: @cas that works from the console (as in running the CGI script as www-data, specifying a shell), but not via apache :(

Comment: That indicates it's not the uid, it's something in the apache config or the apache run-time environment.    Did you test connecting via 127.0.0.1 rather than via the socket, or just test the `su - apache -s /bin/bash`?

Comment: @cas just via su - www... - I think the socket is sane, given it works from console; I'd also prefer to restrict access to only via unix socket, to minimise the security risk

Comment: unix socket is no more secure than loopback IP address.  it's localhost only.   anyway, the  reason for my question was to find out the if the problem was related to the socket somehow, or if it also happened on TCP.   BTW, can you add the output of `ls -lF /tmp/mysql.sock` to your question (not in a comment)

Comment: @cas have added that detail :)

Comment: Is is possible the server is using the auth_socket plug-in? Verify via `SELECT user, plugin FROM mysql.user;`.

Comment: @Hermann users are using `mysql_native_password` (as there are a few PHP scripts that need to work too :/)

Comment: Is apache running in a chroot?  e.g. via `mod_unixd` or `mod_chroot`?   If so, then you have to make sure that mysql's socket is somewhere inside the chroot, or you have to connect to mysql on 127.0.0.1. or both.

Comment: BTW, you seem to think that using 127.0.0.1 is some kind of security hazard.  It isn't.  At all.  127.0.0.1 is the localhost address, accessibly **only** on the server itself (same as the unix socket), and opens no security holes that you wouldn't have with RW access to the unix socket anyway.

Comment: IMO, mysql has always been wrong to mis-interpret the hostname "localhost" as "use the unix domain socket" instead of what "localhost" actually means, which is any address on the host's internal loopback interface (i.e. matching 127.x.x.x).  They could (and should) have used the word "unix" or "socket" or the full path to the actual socket instead.   See [localhost vs. 127.0.0.1 in mysql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1-in-mysql-connect)

Comment: @cas I was hoping to not listen on any IP socket and only use unix sockets to reduce the attack surface - on reflection only listening on the loopback address and closing the unix socket might work just as well. On reflection I wonder if I'm seeing processor architecture issues, on the socket approach, as MySQL was compiled from source (and reports itself as i686), whilst apache was a package install (i386). That might just be stabbing in the dark though.

Comment: There's no increase in attack surface by allowing both 127.0.0.1 and mysqld.sock. They're both restricted to the localhost.   anyway, did it actually work when you tried connecting to 127.0.0.1?  did you check if apache is running in a chroot (if it is, that would make a huge difference).

Comment: I just read your other Q about installing mysql on debian 10.   Your-self compiled mysql may be the cause of the problem....even if it isn't, I strongly recommend uninstalling it and purging all trace of it from your system.  Then installing either the mysql 5.7 in buster, or mariadb (a non-oracle fork of mysql by one of the original founders of mysql).   Is there anything in oracle mysql 8 that you actually KNOW that you need or is it just a case of 8 is bigger than 5.7?  See https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

Answer (score 0):

Apache2 on Debian 9 and 10 is started from systemd. it has

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

in its definition. So processes started from the server don't have access to the regular /tmp and /var/tmp directories. Instead, they have their own directories.

You can either move the socket out of /tmp or start apache2 with

```
PrivateTmp=false
```